# How to delete image created with code and how to interact with it at all

Tags: c#, wpf, image, memory-management

I am working on a game. For this game i create around 200 images in a box 20x10.
My problem is that pressing 1 button creates them a lot of times which garbages the Memory, which i want to avoid. So i created a little if/else function which is supposed to check wether the images were created or not. In case they weren't, code creates them, but if they were, the code should delete them, and i have no idea how to delete code generated images or how to interract with them at all.

```
        public void GameStart(bool load = false)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            Pause.IsEnabled = true;
            Save.IsEnabled = true;
            Shuffle.IsEnabled = true;
            byte datasave = 0;
            int[,] TileID = new int[20,10];
            for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
              for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                {
                    if(TileID[i,j] != 0)
                    {
                        datasave = 1;
                    }
                    TileID[i, j] = rnd.Next(1,9);
                    CreateImage(i, j, TileID[i,j], datasave);
                }
            }
            
        }
        public void CreateImage(int a, int b, int TileID, byte datainfo)
        {
            if(datainfo != 0)
            {
                Image image = new Image();
                image.Width = 40;
                image.Height = 40;
                image.Name = $"Tile{a}{b}";
                image.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                image.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center;
                image.Margin = new Thickness(-1000 + 80 * a, -200 + 80 * b, 0, 0);
                string way = @"C:\Users\ignat\Desktop\Игра\Images\";
                image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(way + $"icon{TileID}.jpg", UriKind.Absolute));
                Grid.Children.Add(image);
            }
            else
            {

                CreateImage(a, b, TileID, datainfo);
            }
```

Comment: Use [File.Delete(string)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.delete?view=net-6.0). There is no difference between files "created with code" or not. What does this even mean (to you)?

Comment: Your code is quite confusing. 1.) You create an array `int[,] TileID = new int[20,10];` and then check every item of it: `TileID[i,j] != 0`. Since you did not add anything, they all are `0`.
2.) `byte datainfo` why is this of type `byte`? My suggestions for this parameter is `bool hasValue` or something. Not sure about the name, because of ... i dont get what you are checking, see 1.).
3.) `if(datainfo != 0)` DoSomthing() but if NOT you call the exact same method with the same parameters again? What do you expect to happen here?

Comment: Basically. I thought to check every single one of them if they don't have an id, so that i don't need to delete them and just assign them a picture instead. The Else thing was a setup for deletion method which i didn't know how to do, so after deleteing everything it was supposed to call method again to create new stuff on top of deleted stuff (which was supposed to prevent garbaging the memory).
But i think i won't check for anything in case button start gets pressed and just delete them and create again.

Comment: @nilsK by image i didn't mean the jpg. I meant that i create the imagebox, which is called "Image" in wpf. And i have no idea how to interract with it if it's created with code.

Comment: My bad, thought you meant the file. What let MS think it was a good idea to give it that name? :s
.. anyway. I'm more the backend guy, but, since you are adding that control to `Grid.Children` and give at a unique name `$"Tile{a}{b}"`, can't you access it that way? I.e. `Grid.Children.Where(x => x.Name == "Title01")` (pseudo-codish). But there might be a more WPF-like approach.

Comment: Many thanks! You are my savior! Didn't think about it from that side!